# Get foreign entitie attributes in AngularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, hibernate, rest

Use case: I have the entities **trip** and **traveler**. So if I get all trips and display them in a table using AngularJS, I want to show the appropriate name of each traveler.

I have a controller which does an API call to **GET** all available trips:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:8080/backend/rest/trip').then(function (trips) {
  $scope.trips = trips.data;
});
```

My response (= trip object):

```
[{"trip_id":2,"traveler_id":5,"currency":null,"rate":100,"description":"Flug nach TXL","dateCreated":null}]
```

Each trip object holds the foreign key ("traveler_id":5) of a traveler that owns the trip. Using the available traveler_id, I want to receive the appropriate firstName and lastName of the traveler that does the trip.

My traveler object:

```
[{"traveler_id":5,"company_id":0,"account":false,"firstName":"Marcel","lastName":"Schmitt"}]
```

All travelers can be received by doing a **GET** request on:

```
http://localhost:8080/backend/rest/traveler
```

How can I implement this in AngularJS?

[using JavaEE + Spring as RESTController + Hibernate for persistence]

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing the exact response and if you can GET the traveler by supplying his id

Comment: @TimCastelijns I updated my answer

Comment: Where do you get the traveler from?

Comment: From a database. I am using Hibernate to persist them.

Comment: I don't really understand exactly what you need. Do you already have the traveler object? Do you want to know how to get the traveler from the DB by supplying a traveler_id?

Comment: Sorry - maybe my question is not worded well. I know how to get both objects, but I don't know how to combine them. So if I get all trips and display them in a table, I want to show the appropriate name of each traveler.

Comment: You'd better return the trips *with their traveller*, using a left join fetch, from the first http query. Loading all the travallers doesn't scale, and making a separate http query for each returned trip doesn't scale either.

Comment: OK thank you @JBNizet, that makes sense. I will try to fetch the travellers using a left join and return both at the same time: trip and traveler.

Comment: @JBNizet I found a post from you about left joins. You are using the following statement `select u from User u left join fetch u.cars where u.id = :id;`. How can I implement this in my DAO? Which class of object will be returned? Thanks

Comment: Well, se a query such as `select trip from Trip trip left join fetch trip.traveller`, and you'll get a list of trips, each trip having its travaller pre-loaded.

Comment: @JBNizet maybe you can help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32527590/hibernate-relations-and-angularjs