# Hibernate relations and AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs, hibernate, jpa

I have this relation between **Travelers** and **Trips** in Hibernate:

[image]

If I want to create a new trip for **traveler 1**, I visit the route **/frontend/#/trip-creation/1** and here I have a form:

[image]

[excerpt of the template]

```
        <form novalidate="novalidate" class="form-horizontal">
          <md-content class="md-padding">
            <div layout layout-sm="column">
              <md-input-container flex>
                <label>Vorname</label>
                <input ng-model="traveler.firstName" disabled>
              </md-input-container>
              <md-input-container flex>
                <label>Nachname</label>
                <input ng-model="traveler.lastName" disabled>
              </md-input-container>
            </div>
            <div layout layout-sm="column">
              <md-input-container flex>
                <label>Wert</label>
                <input required type="number" step="any" name="rate" ng-model="trip.rate" min="0" max="9999999">
              </md-input-container>
              <md-input-container flex>
                <md-select ng-model="trip.currency" placeholder="€">
                  <md-option ng-value="currency" ng-repeat="currency in getCurrencies()">{{currency}}</md-option>
                </md-select>
              </md-input-container>
            </div>
            <div layout layout-sm="column">
              <md-input-container flex>
                <label>Beschreibung</label>
                <textarea ng-model="trip.description" columns="1" md-maxlength="150"></textarea>
              </md-input-container>
            </div>
...
```

By accessing the `$routeParams.id` I can get the details for **traveler 1** like *firstName (= Marcel)* , *lastName* and also *traveler_id*.

```
$scope.traveler = TravelerFactory.show({id: $routeParams.id});
```

That is an example for the **Traveler** object. It contains all the **Trips** a **Traveler** had made so far:

```
[{"traveler_id":1,"company_id":0,"account":false,"firstName":"Marcel","middleName":null,"lastName":"Schmitt","gender":null,"trips":[],"email":null}]
```

**My question:**

1. How can I relate my **traveler 1** with the new created trip

   [{"trip_id":2,**"traveler":null**,"currency":null,"rate":100,"description":"Flug","dateCreated":null}]
2. Is this a proper way of mapping the realtions?

Thank you!

Additional information // backend: Java, Hibernate 4.11, SpringMVC // frontend: AngularJS 1.4.3

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. All you need to send from the angular application is the traveler ID + the fields of the trip to create. Then, on the server, find the traveler by ID, create a new Trip, associate the trip to the traveler and vice-vera, and persist the trip. Since you said that the traveler ID was available in $routeParams.id, I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: @JBNizet You made it a bit more clear to me. I thought the trip including the traveler has to be put together on the client side. Then I have ONE trip object that is send to my backend and persisted. But what you said makes a lot of sense to me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Think about your REST services.

traveler info URL (traveler object):

```
/traveler/:id  ->  #/traveler/1
```

new travel  (traveler object):

```
/traveler/:id/create  ->  #/traveler/1/create
```

existing travel URL  (travel object):

```
/traveler/:id/travel/:travel_id  ->  #/traveler/1/travel/123
```

edit existing travel URL (travel object):

```
/traveler/:id/travel/:travel_id/edit  ->  #/traveler/1/travel/123/edit
```

So, after you add new travel, get successful call back with new travel id (for example: travel_id=456), and redirect to #/traveler/1/travel/456

I am sure you can improve that, just example